# Decay of $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Is it true (is there a commonly known theorem) that says:

$f \in H^1(\mathbb R ^n)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\displaystyle \lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ pointwise (where $H^1$ denotes the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$)?

This can be inferred from the Sobolev embeddings for dimension sufficiently small, but is it true in general?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. You can imagine an infinite sequence of pyramids of height 1 with ever tinier hypersquare bases of area $A_m$, which will clearly be in $L^2$, so long as $\sum |A_m| < \infty$. The question is whether there's enough room for the gradient to remain square integrable. The gradient is like the height over the distance, which is like $|A_m|^{-\frac{1}{n}}$ where $n$ is the spatial dimension, so the requirement is for $\sum |A_m|^{-\frac{2}{n} + 1} < \infty$ as well. When $n = 1$ or $n=2$ this is clearly impossible. For higher dimensions, it is doable.

Comment: You are right @rayyang, I was thinking that the fact $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)=H_0^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ would implie it.

Answer (score 3):

This is true for $n = 1$, but false for $n \ge 2$. Recall, that for $n \ge 2$, there is a positive function $h \in H^1(\mathbb R^n) \setminus L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. Now, take a sequence $\{x_i\}$ with $|x_i| \to \infty$ and define
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} \, h(x - x_i).
$$
Then you have $f(x_i) = +\infty$ for all $i$ (if you want finite function values, take $\tilde x_i$ in a neighbourhood of $x_i$).

See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366853/boundedness-of-functions-in-w-01-p-omega/368116#368116), where I used a similar construction.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine because it covers the case $n=2$, and it illustrates that the failure of the Sobolev-Morrey embedding means that the function can blow up locally at the critical case. For an example of such an $h$, you may consider the function $h(x) = \log (-\log |x|))$ when $|x| < \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and 0 elsewhere.